# Set Variable Value using CSharpCodeProvider

Tags: c#, csharpcodeprovider

I was wondering if there is any way to pass a variable value in a code that will be compiled **One Time** using `CSharpCodeProvider` .

for example :

```
string code = @"
using System;

namespace First
{
    public class Program
    {
       public int Value; // pass this value
        public static void Main()
        {
        " +
            "Console.WriteLine(\"Hello + Value\");"
            + @"
        }
    }
}
```

";

Compile Method :

```
public void Compile(String Code)
{
    CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
    CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();

    parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Drawing.dll");
    parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
    parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;

    CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, Code);
}
```

So i want to be able to pass a value of the `Value` example `2`

and what i meant by `ONE TIME` is like `compile time` so the compiled code will always in its run-time will display the value : `2` whenever i executed the application .

I hope its clear !

Comment: Can you make sure the `code` is in a specific format? E.g. that the value to set is `public int Value = {0};`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved Using Mono.Cecil reference details [Documentatin](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/)